# How does Cell mechanism transfer charges against potential difference

Tags: electricity, potential

In case of a cell,the positive charges (conventionally)move from Higher potential to lower potential..but how actually it happens when charges reach to lower potential terminal of cell ,whether cell is just supplying extra potential energy to the charge and forcing it to go at higher potential level or it happens that cell mechanism uses the charge at low potential in some reaction and produces another charge at higher potential level due to some other reaction..
You can explain it on basis of positive charges or negative charges as well

Comment: This largely depends on what the word "cell" means here. Are you looking for an explanation of the electrochemistry of a certain battery type?

Comment: No I just want to know whether the same charge is transferred from negative potential level to higher potential level or it occurs instep wise manner,ie.a charge is used up at lower potential terminal and simultaneously produced at higher potential terminal

Comment: As I said, the answer to that question depends on what particular kind of power source you're interested in. Is it a battery? A large capacitor? An inductor? A power supply that plugs into mains electricity?

Comment: It Is just a simple battery..